# PHP: how to avoid redeclaring functions?

Tags: php, function, declaration

I tend to get errors such as:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_raw_data_list() (previously declared in /var/www/codes/handlers/make_a_thread/get_raw_data_list.php:7) in /var/www/codes/handlers/make_a_thread/get_raw_data_list.php on line 19

how can I avoid the error? Is it possible to create a IF-clause to check whether a function is declared before declaring it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) as opposed to [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) when including the files that contain your functions.

The *`_once`* siblings of `include` and `require` will force PHP to check if the file has already been included/required, and if so, not `include`/`require` it again, thereby preventing '*cannot redeclare x function...*' fatal errors.

Comment: Although karim79's answer may fix the op's problem, it doesn't actually answer the issue. I think Dooltaz's answer does it correctly.

Comment: is it a good practice opposed to maintainingg code in such a way that no such problem comes up? I mean, `_once` siblings will have to keep track of what's already been included and check it everytim a file is included.

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos This approach is preferable when you can use it. But it only works if the colliding function comes from the same file. One example, where you can't use it, is if the function collides with a function built into php.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have that issue right now.  I'm trying to recreate password_hash() for 5.3

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance Consider https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat Though it doesn't work in PHP prior to 5.3.7, because those have a buggy bcrypt implementation.

Answer (score 102):

```
if(!function_exists("get_raw_data_list")) {
... define function here ...
}
```

http://us.php.net/function_exists

Comment: This can be useful for polyfills i.e. when you want to add a function to an older version of php that was introduced in newer versions of php. In that case `require_once` can't avoid the collision.

Comment: Please note that this code should be **added** before the **usage** of the function

Answer (score 8):

"[function_exists](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)" will tell you if a function has already been declared. Though I suspect maybe you have a problem with including files more than once. When you include a file are you using require_once or include_once or just require / include?

Comment: Technically that's not completely correct. A PHP function might not exist, but still _declared_. e.g. `function_exists` will return `false` for any function defined in `disable_functions` of the PHP configuration. However, those functions are still _declared_.

Comment: For someone who is still interested to know, in the above case commented by fritzmg,
function_exists still won't be benefiting you, since you can't declare the function again by loading file in false case.
Simply
if you use "include_once" or "require_once" anywhere in project you don't need function_exists. But if you still get error, then it is because of any of two cases.
1. You declared function in more than one file.
2. some where else in project you are using require or include two times for including the same file.  Or by once require and once by include.

Answer (score 5):

If you are dealing with Classes `method_exists()` might be what you're looking for:

```
if(!method_exists(__CLASS__, 'function_name')){
    function function_name(){

    }
}
```

This will check the current Class to make that the function `function_name` doesn't exist before trying to declare it