# Calling multiple functions from the same PHP resource

Tags: php

On my page I'm trying to run two functions from the same .PHP document, however I was getting the error "function already declared".

I had a look here: [PHP: how to avoid redeclaring functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384006/php-how-to-avoid-redeclaring-functions)

After looking at this I changed my code to:

```
            <?php

            include_once('resource/buildtalentpage.php');

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
            echo getTalentDetails($row);
            }   

            ?>




///////////   Loads of HTML   ///////////




            <?php

            include_once('resource/buildtalentpage.php');

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
            echo getTalent($row);
            }   

            ?>
```

The good news is, I don't get the error any more. The bad news is, that function 'getTalent' no longer seems to be called?

Comment: You don't need to include `resource/buildtalentpage.php` twice.

Comment: What code is in resource/buildtalentpage.php?

Comment: You need to split up your php files (1) files that _declare_ clases, constants, functions (which should be `*_once`'d. (2) Files that _do_ stuff (which should NOT be `*_once`'d. Most likely, you want to move the `getTalent()` function definition to a different file, in use `include_once` in _buildtalentpage.php_ to include the definition there (that seems to be doing other stuff as well which should run on _every_ `include`).

Comment: along with not including the same file twice, you can use [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if a function has been defined before, before attempting to create it

Comment: @Wrikken Are you saying that I should have `getTalentDetails` and `getTalent` in different files? I did have this set up which worked, however I was trying to make the code cleaner, with as few files as possible.

Comment: Few files is not necessarily better, a lot of files isn't either. What I'm saying is you need to separate function declarations & classes from code that does something. I _assumed_ (as I look at the accepted wrongly, my apologies) that `buildtalentpage.php` _both_ defined your `getTalent*()` functions, _and_ give you the `$result2` resource, which should not happen. As it turns out, my assuming was wrong, making an ass of myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set from mysql doesn't get reset so your second loop condition returns false the first time through, hence the code never gets called. The easiest thing to do here is do all of your work in one loop.

```
<?php

    include_once('resource/buildtalentpage.php');
    $talentHtml = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo getTalentDetails($row);
        $talentHtml.= getTalent($row);
    }   

    ?>

///////////   Loads of HTML   ///////////

<?php
    echo $talentHtml;
```

Comment: Ahhh, so it's looping from the end, i.e, nothing? This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the file that defines your function one time only. You can then call the function as many times as needed

Comment: They're two different functions with similar names.

Comment: I was referring to the include_once that you have twice on the page. Presumably both functions are defined in the included file?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The problem is that if I don't have the `include` or `include_once` the function seems to be ignored?

Comment: I would recommend just using "include" instead of "include_once" at the very top of the document. Then you should be able to use any of the functions in the included page anywhere in your php file as many times as you like.