# php fatal eror Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php, redeclare

gettng the below even though the file is quotes is the file I am using and the line is the exact line of the actual function declaration ?

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sortByTest() (previously declared in ."file"... line .."123"

Comment: This really isn't a valid question, the error is fully self-explanatory. You're obviously including a file twice or something. In that case, use include_once / require_once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: how to avoid redeclaring functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384006/php-how-to-avoid-redeclaring-functions)

Answer (score 1):

It just means you're including that file twice. The first time it is included, everything is fine. The next time it is included, PHP goes through the file again, gets to the "function sortByTest(...)" declaration and it goes BOOM because it already had the function defined in memory.

To solve this, change the part where you're including the file to one of:

```
   include_once "..."
   or
   require_once "..."
```

I recommend `require_once` if it is not a view template file.

Comment: Thanks guys - realised I had declared the function in a (quite long ) loop!