# Using Function Exists and Require Once - STILL Fatal Error: Previously Declared

Tags: php, function, require

This has come up a bazillion times, I know, but the expected solutions - `! function_exists()` and `require_once()` -  are not working. The question is (and I have done a lot of searching) is there any way to determine at a given point of execution if a function is ***declared*** but not ***exists?***

That almost makes no sense typing it out, but that is what is happening. Details:

Here is what we have and where the fatal is thrown:

```
if (! function_exists('some_function')) {
   require_once('file-containing-the-function.php');
}
```

```
Fatal error: cannot redeclare some_function, previously declared in file-containing-the-function.php on line XX . . . .
```

You would think the combination of `function_exists()` and `require_once()` (or include_once, tried that as well) would prevent this issue, but in this environment it does not.

The most insightful tidbit I found was in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384006/php-how-to-avoid-redeclaring-functions#answer-1384017) :

> A PHP function might not exist, but still declared.

Hence my question, which there doesn't appear to be a good answer for (other than rebuilding the entire system correctly, which is Not Going to Happen Any Time Soon.)

This is in a huge legacy system with global variables and functions everywhere. There are no namespaces and very few classes, plenty of places for things to go wrong. I know the issue lies somewhere in that problem - `file-containing-the-function.php` is included in an include of an include and so on, many layers deep (a stack trace doesn't even show it.). Even so, by all description, definition, and multitudes of responses on S.O. the wrappers should work.

At the point of this code it does not come up in `get_defined_functions()`. Everything is global and top level, there are no functions inside functions or any of the usual suspects, like an overlooked extra include. `require_once()` is also applied in the other files where `file-containing-the-function.php` is included. get_included_files() files not show that file `file-containing-the-function.php` has even been included at the point of this code's execution.

The file that this code lives in is an include itself and inherits `some_function()` from another include somewhere else. I cannot move the include of this file or this code up the call stack far enough to ensure this is executed first (and would break a lot of other things if I did.) This code **has** to exist where it does, as this particular file may be included without including `file-containing-the-function.php`. For example, this may be among 20 or 30 other includes in practical use for a web page output, but when you unit test it, only this file is included.

This is such a simple and basic thing, any way to determine if a global function is ***declared?***

Comment: Unless you use the `disabled_functions` setting in php.ini, that other comment is not relevant.

Comment: What he appears to be saying there is **even if you disabled them, they are still declared." Admittedly grasping at straws, this has me a bit baffled. :-\

Comment: I understand, but if you haven't disabled them using that, then declared == exists.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but many years ago in much older versions of PHP (4.x?) on Windows I found that if you `include_once('D:/foo.php')` and later `include_once('d:/foo.php')`, PHP considered them to be different files, presumably because the drive letter was a different case (even though Windows filenames are case-insensitive). I'm not sure how this applies to more modern PHP versions on non-Windows systems but is it possible that your system thinks they are different files even when they map to the same physical file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what's going on, because the error message implies that the file is being required multiple times, even though you used `require_once`. The whole point of the `_once` versions of `require` and `include` is to prevent redefinitions.

Instead of putting the `if` statement around `require_once`, put it in `file-containing-the-function.php`, and then use `require_once` unconditionally.

```
if (!function_exists('some_function')) {
    function some_function(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I would try anything but `file-containing-the-function.php` cannot be edited (long story and one of the reasons the system has grown so out of control.) It's a bit like a house of cards. I never would have thought to remove the if wrapper, but just tried it in this implementation. Same result. Require once should mean . . . require once! :-D

Comment: All I can think of is that you're sometimes requiring it without `_once`, unless there's a bug in `require_once`. Could you have multiple copies of `file-containing-the-function.php` in different folders?

Comment: Thank you, oh definitely there are multiple implementations including this file. It appears to be using require_once() across the board. Imagine though, if it weren't, when it gets to **this** require_once() in my call, it wouldn't include it again.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I thought maybe the `_once` statements would only check if the file had previously been included with another `_once` statement, but I just tested it and they also check if it was included with a non-once version. So I can't understand why it's being loaded twice.

Comment: My question wasn't about multiple places including the file, it was about multiple versions of the file being included. The once directives do duplicate detection by full pathname.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is still interested to know, in the comment you referred by fritzmg,
function_exists still won't be benefiting you, since you can't declare the function again by loading file in false case.
Simply
if you use `"include_once"` or `"require_once"` anywhere in project you don't need `function_exists`. But if you still get error, then it is because of any of **two cases**.

**1**. You declared function in more than one files in the project.

**2**. Some where else in project you are using require or include two times for including the same file.  Or doing once by require and once by include.