# why use function_exist for every function in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, helper

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('test_method'))
{
    function test_method($var = '')
    {
        return $var;
    }   
}
```

this is very common code from CI helper and there is nothing fancy but may I know whydo we use this function_exist for every function inside it . I mean why don't we directly create function like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    function test_method($var = '')
    {
        return $var;
    }
```

is this approach bad or what exactly this line do

i also know what function_exists return as it return bool value and checks if any functions exists or not

so anybody can please explain .
Thank you !!

Comment: Functions are mostly provided by themes and plugins and it may be that you have not enabled / yet loaded required code thats why you use function_exists in wordpress to check if functions are actually available.

Comment: Another common use case for this is to allow other / 3rd-party scripts to _overwrite_ functionality. If your own code gets included _before_ this, then it can define `test_method` itself, and have it do something different or more, than the version the framework provides. If the framework did _not_ check, before it tried to declare the function, you'd end up with a "cannot redeclare function test_method" in that kind of situation.

Comment: sorry to interrupt but can you please explain in easy context

Comment: You can define a function only **once** with a specific name (in your case test_method). If you try to define another function or the same function under the same name then [you'll get an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384006/php-how-to-avoid-redeclaring-functions). Thats why you check with function_exists, whether the function already exists ... to prevent this exception being thrown ... since it could happen that your overall script/application loads the file which defines this function more than once.